# Determine the expected value of $X$ using indicator random variables

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer. Consider a uniformly random permutation $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_n$ of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots , n\}$. Define random variable $X$ to be the number of indices $i$ for which $1 \leq i \lt n$ and $a_i < a_{i+1}$.

Determine the expected value $E(X)$ of $X$. (Hint: Use indicator random variables.)

---

I know that $X_i = 1$, if $a_i \lt a_{i+1}$ and $0$, otherwise

So I have determined that $E(X) = P(X_i=1)$ but I am not sure how to figure out what the $P(X_i=1)$ is.

Comment: $E[X] = E[I_1+I_2+\ldots+I_n] = P[X_1=1] + P[X_2=1] + \ldots + P[X_n=1]$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: The events $a_i\lt a_{i+1}$ and $a_{i+1}\lt a_i$ are equally likely.

Comment: So would that make E(X) = 1/2?

Comment: @Kayseta:  $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{2}$ so $E(X)=(n-1)\cdot\frac{1}{2}$.